# Back Button Handling in SlidingDrawer for mulitple fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

I have searched for this solution many times but couldn't find what i want.I have a slidingdrawer in my app.Now the options in the drawer is:
1.**Home**
2.**Friends**
3.**Groups** and many more
Now for every option i have many fragments.Like for **Home** and **Friends** option the fragments goes like 
`Home->fragment1->fragment2->fragment3`
`Friends->fragment4->fragment5` 
**Case 1:** Now when i go to frament1 from Home and then to frament2 and again clicking Friends and then go to fragment4.Now when i press `Back Button` it is also showing the fragments of the `Home` .But i want to restrict the `Back` button to show only it's options fragment i.e it won't show the fragment of `Home` using Back button when i am in `Friends`.**How to do it in slidingdrawer activity and what to do in the corresponding fragments??**
**Case 2:** What i see in my app is that when i was pressing Back button sometimes i could see my fragment over another fragment i.e i could see two fragments mixed up.**Why didn't it replace the fragment fully??**

Now what i implemented in my `SlidingDrawer`:

```
Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment(); // i have this initialized previously for every item of listview
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
```

and What i did to go to another fragment from this fragment.For example: in 
`HomeFragment` to goto another fragment i did:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = new FriendsStatusFragment();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();
```

In some Fragment this works nice but sometimes the problem of `case 2` occurs and the back button is not working according to my desire mentioned in `case 1` .Can anyone Show me Path??Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you don't return to fragments within Home when you're in Friends, call `popBackStack` before you load in the Friends fragment (when you switch Options) to clear all the fragments in the back stack.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new FriendsStatusFragment();
popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Can u plz show me in code and explain it..It will help me greatly..thanks in advance..